# Your app is using an incorrect implementation of in-app billing

Tags: android, android-security

Your app is using an incorrect implementation of in-app billing. Please see this Google Help Center article for more information.

**Next Steps**

1. If you are using IabHelper, please start using the latest SDK.
2. If you are manually invoking the in-app billing service, make sure you are calling `Intent.setPackage(“com.android.vending”)` on any intents to `"com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"`.
3. Sign in to your Developer Console and submit the updated version of your app.
4. Check back after five hours - we’ll show a warning message if the app hasn’t been updated correctly

I got this mail even though I'm using following code.

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
                    serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
                    bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn,
                            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

what actual issue can be there? why google is giving this warning?

Comment: @VishalPatoliya I just want to know that why google is giving this warning? and How to fix this if it is a major issue.

Comment: SHOW US full code where you implemented in-app billing

Answer (score 3):

You might be using an older version of Google Play Services, which has the incorrect usage.  Try updating to the latest

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38667014/2339757